# 301 Redirect Loop Migrating Blog from Subdomain to Root (Blogger to Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I was hosting my blogspot blog under a custom subdomain (http://blog.jamminglobal.com) and now I've moved over to a self-hosted wordpress site and have moved the blog to the root. I imported the blogspot into wp and set a 301 on the blogspot theme page. Most of the pages redirect correctly but some are stuck in a loop. I did not change my .htaccess and can't seem to figure out why only some pages are stuck in a loop and others redirect correctly.

This is the code I put in my old blogspot theme for the 301 (I got it from a wp plugin). I think I need to put a www somewhere, right? This is placed in the head:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<link href='http://jamminglobal.com/' rel='canonical'/>
<meta content='0;url=http://jamminglobal.com/' http-equiv='refresh'/>
<b:else/>
<link expr:href='&quot;http://jamminglobal.com/?br=&quot; + data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
<meta expr:content='&quot;0;url=http://jamminglobal.com/?br=&quot; + data:blog.url' http-equiv='refresh'/>    
</b:if>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var wpblog = &quot;http://jamminglobal.com/?br=&quot;;
wpblog = wpblog  + window.location.href.replace(&#39;http:&#39;,&#39;&#39;);
window.location.replace(wpblog);
</script>
<b:skin>
```

An example page stuck in the loop are:
http://jamminglobal.com/2010/02/frequently-asked-questions-faq.html

(I searched and read all the related threads and didn't find an answer.)